# React native UIExplorer example not building on device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am able to build React native example app UIExplorer on the simulator from Xcode but building it on a device gives an error

```
Unhandled JS Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Parse Error
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]